# Detecting if argument is Javascript HTML Element datatype

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I need a XB (Cross Browser) method of detecting if an argument is a HTML Element.

Using the following code gives different results in different browsers:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(element);
// returns in FF "[object HTMLDivElement]";
// returns in IE "[object Object]";
```

The other method I found was:

```
if(element.nodeType)  // true for a HTML Element;
```

Does someone knows a XB tested solution?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120262/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-if-a-given-javascript-object-is-a-dom-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
if (element.nodeType === element.ELEMENT_NODE)
// Element.prototype.ELEMENT_NODE === 1
```

`if (element.nodeType)` is almost always true. For example, the nodeType of a comment is 8, so it would be detected as an element with your code even though it isn't.

Comment: You have to compare against `1` explicitly. Although the symbolic constant `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` has been defined since the earliest DOM Level 1 Core specs, IE does not provide it.